g++ very different behaviour with vs without optimization flags
The following code gives drastically different results when compiling with any optimization flags vs without:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

// trailing zero count for __uint128_t
int u128_ctz(__uint128_t n) {
    int count_hi = __builtin_ctzll(uint64_t(n >> 64));
    int count_lo = __builtin_ctzll(uint64_t(n));

    return count_lo == 64 ? 64 + count_hi : count_lo;
}

int main() {
    __uint128_t one = 1;
    __uint128_t t = one << 122;

    std::cout << u128_ctz(t) << '\n';

    return 0;
}


When compiled plainly with g++ main.cpp, 122 is printed as I expected. However with optimizations the result becomes 64.
Despite __builtin_ctzll(0ull) being undefined behavior, a simple print statement above the return shows that it does find the correct value.
My question is not about the undefined behavior of __builtin_ctzll(0ull). I am asking why this issue only arises when optimizations are enabled?

The GCC documentation for __builtin_ctzll say that it's like __builtin_ctz. And the documentation for __builtin_ctz say that __builtin_ctz(0) is undefined. You can't trust the result you get because of that. If you want to check if uint64_t(n) is zero, you need to check that explicitly.

@Someprogrammerdude I see, however if I add a print statement right above the return statement, it will print out that count_lo = 64, so count_lo seems to get the correct value regardless of the optimization level. How can it go wrong only at the comparison if the UB is the return value of the function?

"without any optimization flags vs without" -- I don't understand.

@3CxEZiVlQ I meant to write "with vs without"

The problem with undefined behavior is that it's, well, undefined. The compiler is free to do whatever it wants, and sometimes it seems like there's just no rhyme or reason. If something is undefined, then there's really no use in discussing the behavior, unless you want to discuss the intricacies of a specific implementation (very specific, down to the exact version and host and target system).

Being undefined includes being inconsistent.

It's completely logical. If you look at count_lo == 64 ? 64 + count_hi : count_lo while knowing that __builtin_ctzll(uint64_t(0)) is undefined but its "intuitive" value would be 64, the condition can be assumed to be false (you can always assume that undefined behaviour doesn't occur). Thus, the result is always count_lo, so there is no need to check.

int u128_ctz(__uint128_t n) {
    int count_hi = __builtin_ctzll(uint64_t(n >> 64));
    int count_lo = __builtin_ctzll(uint64_t(n));

    if (count_lo == 64) {
        std::cout << "count_lo == 64\n";
    }

    return count_lo == 64 ? 64 + count_hi : count_lo;
}

After I added an if statement before return, it seems that the O1 optimization assumes count_lo will never return 64, so it ignored my condition and returned count_lo directly.
I think this is the code after O1 optimization:
// O1 optimized
int u128_ctz(__uint128_t n) {
    return __builtin_ctzll(uint64_t(n));
}


I see, is it correct then to say that since __builtin_ctz(0ull) is undefined, that the compiler is free to ignore the possibility of it occurring, and thus never performs the comparison?

@dsa - When something is undefined (in this case, by the compiler developers) a compiler is free to do anything.  Or not.   One possible outcome is for observably different behaviours with or without some optimisations enabled.

The code after optimization is actually just the value 64 inlined.
